# How to transfer/migrate tables with schema from SQL Server to Oracle?

Tags: sql, sql-server, connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have tables from my SQL Server 2008 R2 that have a schema. I manage to transfer some tables to sql developer but the tables with schema did't transfer. How to do?.

Comment: You mean schema for structure or owner??

Comment: @RajeshRanjan, I'm not an expert to sql but I think it is for structure. For example I have a table name Region.RegionPlace and dbo.Place something like that. I only manage to transfer the tables that has a dbo.****.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DTS (Data Transformation Service) at SQL Server Side or you can configure Gateway at oracle side. To Use DTS you should have oracle client on the machine where you are executing DTS.

DTS will ask you for source and destination and it's credential. So as you need to migrate from SQL to Oracle. In source tab select "Microsoft OLEDB Provide for SQL Server" as Data Source, Put IP Address / Server Name in Server Name DDown. If you have Window Authentication then let it be and select database and go to Next. If you have login ID and Password, select SQL Server Authentication put Login Id and Password, Select you database and then click on Next button.

In destination Tab select "Microsoft OLEDB Provider for Oracle", then click on Properties. And put TNSName into Server Name (You configured using NETCA in Oracle Client on the machine) and LoginId and Password.

After you get connected it will display to use query or complete table, you just click on next without selecting any option.

Then it will display all tables from source, select the table you need to migrate then click on next till finish.

For Gateway configuration, take help from this link.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/gateways.111/b31043/conf_sql.htm

Thanks